# 2008 Jeep Wrangler 3.8L V6 going into high RPMs on highway

Tags: automatic-transmission

I’m not sure if this is normal, but when I get on the highway the car maxes out at 55-60mph, and if i barely press the gas any farther the engine gets super loud and goes into high RPMs. I was wondering if that was normal, or if there’s legitimately something wrong with it.

Comment: what is the rpm when doing 55mph? is it an auto and just changing down to accelerate?

Comment: It’s doing about 2,500rpms and 3,500-4,500 when it gets really loud, and it’s an auto. The engine is a 3.8L V8 in a 2008 Jeep Wrangler Unlimited X